# unable to see changes on a recipe

Tags: chef-recipe

I have generated a cookbook,added a recipe and uploaded.  After running the chef-client on node I found my recipe is not proper and I need to edit this. I am unable to see my changes done on recipe, I uploaded it again and again not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,and it worked:
First we need to change the cookbook version, and cd to cookbook directory-> run knife upload cookbookname.